# npm install error :SocksProxyAgent is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, github, npm, jitsi-meet

error log:

```
50 warn skipping integrity check for git dependency https://git@github.com/jitsi/strophejs-plugin-stream-management.git
51 warn skipping integrity check for git dependency https://git@github.com/jitsi/rnnoise-wasm.git
52 warn skipping integrity check for git dependency https://git@github.com/jitsi/react-native-video.git
53 warn skipping integrity check for git dependency https://git@github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated.git
54 warn skipping integrity check for git dependency https://git@github.com/jitsi/sdp-interop.git
55 silly audit bulk request failed undefined
56 verbose audit error TypeError: SocksProxyAgent is not a constructor
56 verbose audit error     at getProxy (/Users/xb2022/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/lib/agent.js:201:12)
56 verbose audit error     at getAgent (/Users/xb2022/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/lib/agent.js:67:19)
56 verbose audit error     at remoteFetch (/Users/xb2022/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/lib/remote.js:31:17)
56 verbose audit error     at fetch (/Users/xb2022/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/lib/fetch.js:99:13)
56 verbose audit error     at makeFetchHappen (/Users/xb2022/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/lib/index.js:10:10)
56 verbose audit error     at doFetch (/Users/xb2022/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-fetch/lib/index.js:108:15)
56 verbose audit error     at async Map.[getReport] (/Users/xb2022/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/audit-report.js:333:21)
56 verbose audit error     at async Map.run (/Users/xb2022/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/audit-report.js:106:19)
57 silly audit error undefined
58 timing auditReport:getReport Completed in 610ms
59 silly audit report null
```

This is error logging in NPM install;
Has this happened to anyone?

Comment: npm install error :SocksProxyAgent is not a constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NPM and Git need add Network proxy！
NPM configuration：

```
npm config set proxy http://127.0.0.1:1088
npm config set https-proxy http://127.0.0.1:1088
npm config set strict-ssl false

cancel：
npm config delete proxy
npm config delete https-proxy
```

Git configuration：

```
git config --global http.proxy http://127.0.0.1:1088
git config --global https.proxy https://127.0.0.1:1088

cancel：
git config --global --unset http.proxy
git config --global --unset https.proxy
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer wasn't working for me, yet here's a temporary solution I figured out.

After checking the error log from message:

```
# npm install
npm ERR! SocksProxyAgent is not a constructor

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023... .log
```

we can find where the exception was thrown (search text `TypeError: SocksProxyAgent is not a constructor` ), to solve the problem, modify the file `agent.js` to disable proxy temporary, (on my machine, the full path was `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/lib/agent.js`).

Modify the function `checkNoProxy` to make it always return true, i.e.

```
function checkNoProxy (uri, opts) {
  return true; // remove this line after `npm install` done
  //other original code 
}
```

I am running docker with a global proxy, and I guessed the npm implementation would use the system ones.

This situation is that the `socks-proxy-agent` is not installed but we would have to use it to install libraries when we are using proxy, a antinomy.